# Insert mysql date range, add different value every 7 days (work-shift calendar)

Tags: mysql, date, join, calendar, range

I am trying to make a work-shift calendar where an employee can work 30 hours in one week, but 40 in another.

Each employee can have multiple different weeks, each which can have different work days, hours.

If an employee for example would have 2 different work weeks, on the calendar it should look something like this:

```
 1 | 01-01-2015 | week1 | employee1
 2 | 01-02-2015 | week1 | employee1
 3 | 01-03-2015 | week1 | employee1
 4 | 01-04-2015 | week1 | employee1
 5 | 01-05-2015 | week1 | employee1
 6 | 01-08-2015 | week2 | employee1
 7 | 01-09-2015 | week2 | employee1
 8 | 01-10-2015 | week2 | employee1
```

How would i fill a calendar table with a range of dates, adding a different week_id every 7 days according to data from another table?

```
**Calendar table columns:**

- id
- date
- week_id
- employee_id

**Employee table columns:**

- id
- day_id
- employee_id
- week_id
- work_hours_from
- work_hours_to
```

Employee table example data:

[image: table data]

i've tried the following, which comes close, but the dates are all the same date which results in an infinite loop:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS filldates;
CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN

  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO prefix_calendar (date,week_id,employee_id)
    SELECT date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY),week_id,employee_id FROM prefix_employee_hours WHERE employee_id = 5;
  END WHILE;
END;

CALL filldates('2011-05-01','2011-05-05');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't the know if the logic is correct in the loop, but you need to increment `dateStart` if you want it to terminate:

So add:

```
set dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

just before the `END WHILE`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer i see that by forgetting to set the dateStart interval it keeps looping since there aren't days being added to the initial starting date. Your solution gets me even closer to what i need, except that now it adds double dates for each week_id (7x 2011-05-01 for week1, and 7x 2011-05-01 for week2) where i seek to get this instead: 7x 2011-05-01 for week1, 7x 2011-05-02 for week2, 7x 2011-05-03 for week1, 7x 2011-05-04 for week2 etc.etc.